# How get upload progress for multiple multipart upload task

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, alamofire

i am using below code for upload progress ,but if i upload 4 images how to get  progress for indiviudal upload .

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in

                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: alamoName, fileName: alamoFileName, mimeType: alamoMimeType)
                for (key, value) in parameters {
                    multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
            },to:requestUrl){ (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let upload, _,_):
                    upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                        print("Upload Progress:%d", progress)
                    })
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        if(response.result.value != nil){
                            let uploadResponse = response.result.value as! Dictionary <String ,Any>
                            self.didUpdateResponse(sender: uploadResponse)
                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
```

Comment: see this https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1652#issuecomment-259020449

Comment: see this also https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/989

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have four uploads (I assume we're talking about four separate uploads and not a single request with four files uploaded), each Alamofire `upload` object already has its own `uploadProgress` property.

So, if you're using `UIProgressView`, you don't need to implement `uploadProgress` *method* (like you do in your example) at all, but rather just set the `observedProgress` of your `UIProgressView` to the `uploadProgress` *property* of the Alamofire `upload`.

Answer (score -2):

Please make use of NSOperationQueue and NSOperation. You need to subclass NSOperation to perform downloading of images. Use image id or URL to distinguish image download progress. Also, you can use the block to notify the observer to update the progress.